# Angular 2 Component - How to export interface?

Tags: angular, interface, components

I have developed a header component that requires data as "IHeader" type

**header.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
      CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
      HeaderComponent       
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent
  ]

})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

**IHeader.ts**

```
export interface IHeader {
    headerName: string;
    headerTitle: string;   
    headerVisible: boolean;
    headerAttributes:IheaderAttributes;
    headerType:string;
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() data: IHeader;

}
```

How can I export "IHeader" interface ?

**Additional Info**

I have created this as a module that other in house products can install as node module using "npm install ... ". Developers can import the component in their products but how to limit a user to pass the data in a certain format ?

Comment: in component.ts import {IHeader} from 'location/IHeader'

Comment: Did you try importing it the same way you import other things?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have added more info to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-part-2-6e2bc1e14121) if you want to build an angular library/package.

You should be able to export your interface in the `interface_api.ts` file.
Note that with this trick, you need to import your interface definition in your modules/components/services.
But the advantage is that your feature modules will depend on library and thus features modules will be reusable in other projects.

So  this way you can import your interface definition from a library (angular package) without the need of relying on folder structure in your project.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I have build an angular package and it is working fine. The only thing I am struggling with is how to export an interface. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, if you have built an angular library, you should  have an entry file named api_public.ts. In this file you can export your classes or interfaces, like : export * from ‘path/to/your/interface.ts ». Then in your angular app you can import classes/interfaces from your lib, e.g : import {your interface} from ‘my-angular-lib’. Note that i have not try it, but according to what i habe read it shiuld work. Let me know !

Comment: Link does not work, hence the downvote.

Comment: Hi, since the initial link is very old (2018), i little 10 secondes google search and I found it : https://indepth.dev/posts/1120/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-using-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr

Comment: If you identified an outdated link in your answer, please [edit] to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

> Here is the way to **export the interface**

Example:

```
// car interface
// '?' shows that this property is optional
export interface car {
  isCar?: boolean; 
  wheels?: number;
  engine?: string;
  engineType?: string;
}
```

You need to add **export** keyword to export this interface to other components.

Suppose you need to import this interface in **another component...**
Then, you can refer to this code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// import interface named car
import { car } from '@app/car.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-collection',
  templateUrl: './carCollection.component.html'
})
export class HyundaiCarComponent implements OnInit {

  // Here.. You can give HyundaiCar variable of type car
  HyundaiCar: car = {

   isCar= true,
   wheels= 4,
   engine= '4-stroke',
   engineType= 'petrol'  
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```